# Find number in interval with small prime factors

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, prime-factorization

Given two natural numbers `A` and `B` where `A + 1 < B`, and a prime number `P` with `P < A`.

Is there a natural number `X` with `A < X < B` with prime factors `p_i` which are all `p_i <= P`?

Examples ([table of prime factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_prime_factors)):

- `A=15, B=17, P=2` gives `X=16=2^4`
- `A=100, B=109, P=7` gives `X=105=3*5*7` or `X=108=2^2*3^3`
- `A=216, B=225, P=5` has no such `X`

Naive solution: Enumerate all candidates `X_c` with `A < X_c < B`, and check their prime factors to be all less than / equal to `P`.

Is there a better way of finding an `X` (perhaps with some probability)? Or some way of saying *whether* there exist such an `X`?  Or some probability of *whether* there exist such an `X`?

Comment: I'd appreciate help with tagging my question :)

Comment: The problem is too unconstrained to have a pat answer. You select $A,B,P$ completely arbitrarily, and ask whether some fourth number exists with particular properties. You can say that if $A$ is not a power of $2$ and $B\ge 2A$ then there will exist some $X=2^n$ which falls between them and will perforce have the property you desire, but beyond that, all other outcomes are possible depending on the particular choices of $A,B,P$.

Comment: I believe you are asking about the distribution of $P-$smooth numbers.  The asymptotic density is available, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) for instance, but I believe it is hard to say a lot about particular intervals.

Comment: There will always be numbers divisible by the factors of the length of the interval inclusive of one endpoint.

Comment: @lulu Wow, thanks, I didn't know that there's a name for that. This indeed helps a lot!